# htaccess rewrite causing jplayer stop music while changing pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I have a strange problem, i tried to rewrite urls via htaccess on a music sharing script but now every time i change page the music playing stops.

The rules I have is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^admin$ index.php?a=admin [L]
```

If i click the link *www.domain.com/index.php?a=admin* it works great

If i click *www.domain.com/admin*

The title of the page change to

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use this code in .htaccess .. I really can't remember from where I got this code but it works for me .. hope it will work with you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

if it not work .. try to remove `/` from `/index.php` to be just `index.php` and try again

Comment: @GeezyBang even after you remove / before index.php??